Showing particular quotient space is (not) compact, connected and Hausdorff
I came across the following question, I'm unsure about some of my answers.

Let $U = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2} \mid y \in \{0, 1\}\}$ be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. We define the following equivalence relation on $U$, $\forall x \in \mathbb{Q} \colon (x, 0) \sim (x, 1)$.

Now the following questions apply to this context.

Is $U/\sim$ compact?

This is not the case, because $U/\sim$ is not bounded. Alternatively, an open cover of $U/~$ would cover uncountably many points with an irrational $x$-coordinate. These cannot be covered with a finite number of open sets.

Is $U/\sim$ connected?

I thought so, I wanted to show that $U/\sim$ is path connected. We can check a few cases on the pairs of points. Two points on the same line are joined by said line. The points $(x_{1}, 0)$ and $(x_{2}, 1)$ where $x_{1}, x_{2} \in \mathbb{R}\setminus Q$ can be joined by a path as well. We can travel along the $x$-axis to some $(x_{3}, 0)$ with $x_{3} \in \mathbb{Q}$, which is identified with $(x_{3}, 1)$. Then we can travel along the line $y = 1$ to $(x_{2}, 1)$. The rest of the cases are similar. Is my intuition correct?

Is $U/\sim$ Hausdorff?

I'm unsure about this in particular, I know that $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$ where rational points are identified is not Hausdorff. I thought that a similar argument would apply but that's not the case. Any tips are appreciated, I'm likely overlooking something.

@Malady Yes I can! Thank you. I’m curious though, if there is another way to do the third part?  Since it is Hausdorff, and in the source material they were asked separately.

"Alternatively, an open cover of $U/\sim$ would cover uncountably many points with an irrational $x$-coordinate. These cannot be covered with a finite number of open sets." This argument doesn't make sense since $[a,b]$ is compact and has uncountably many irrational points. Neither does the boundedness, as the answer says.

Your arguments for the first two parts are generally good. For the first part, it technically does not make sense to call $V = U / \sim$ "unbounded" unless there is a metric that induces the topology. (Such a metric indeed does not exist, as we will show that $U / \sim$ is not Hausdorff.) Despite the absence of such a metric, you can still pick a cover for $V$ that consists of sets of the form $q((x - 1, x + 1) \times \{0, 1\})$, with $x \in \mathbb{Z}$, where $q: U \to V$ is the quotient map inducing "$\sim$". These sets cover $V$, and there is clearly no finite subset of them that cover $V$.
For the third part, I claim that $V$ is not Hausdorff. Consider the points $a = \{e \times 0\} \ne b = \{e \times 1\} \in V$, where $e$ is your favorite irrational number (i.e., $e \in \mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q}$). Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint neighborhoods of $a$ and $b$, respectively. Then $q^{-1} (A)$ is open in $U$ and contains the point $e \times 0$; similarly, $q^{-1} (B)$ is open in $U$ and contains the point $e \times 1$. These imply (along with the definition of the product toplology) that $q^{-1} (A)$ (resp. $q^{-1} (B)$) must contain a basis element $(e - \varepsilon_a, e + \varepsilon_a) \times \{0\}$ (resp. $(e - \varepsilon_b, e + \varepsilon_b) \times \{1\}$). Let $\varepsilon = \min \{ \varepsilon_a, \varepsilon_b\} > 0$. Since the rationals are dense in the reals, there is some rational number $k$ such that $k \in (e - \varepsilon, e + \varepsilon)$. Then $k \times 0 \in q^{-1} (A)$ and $k \times 1 \in q^{-1} (B)$, which means that the point $q (k \times 0) = q (k \times 1) = \{k \times 0, k \times 1\} \in V$ belongs to both $A$ and $B$. This contradicts the hypothesis that $A, B$ are disjoint. Intuitively, "gluing" the corresponding rational numbers on the two lines has also made it impossible to separate (with open sets) corresponding irrational numbers on the lines.
